# Google sheets - Script to use columns headings?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, custom-function, google-sheets-formula

Have two questions here, I have a rather complex spreadsheet where I need to move around columns and it will take forever to update the queries as it's going to be a regular task. I've decided to update the query to use a column header which hopefully will make it more flexible.

I thought I was on the right track with the script below but it doesn't do anything in the sheet

```
  function getHeader(sheet, headings) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var headings = sheet.getDataRange().offset(0, 0, 1).getValues()[0];


}
```

This is how I'm calling the script in the sheet

```
=query(A:F,"select "&getHeader("Name")&" where "&getHeader("Role")&" contains 'Cook' ",0)
```

I've got it working using a query below which seems to work well, I'm interested to know what would be better Script or query?

```
=query(A:E,"select "&char(64+match("Name",1:1,0))&" where "&char(64+match("Role",1:1,0))&" = 'Cook' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using column names instead of their indexes directly.

You'll need three columns Side1, Side2 and Hypotenuse.  I named my sheet 'hypotenuse'.

You pick the lengths of the sides and it calculates the hypotenuse for that right triangle.

```
function hypotenuse() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('hypotenuse');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var vObj={};
    for(var n=0;n<vA[i].length;n++){
      vObj[vA[0][n]]=vA[i][n];
      vObj[vA[0][n]+'idx']=vA[0].indexOf(vA[0][n])
    }
    vObj.Hypotenuse=Math.sqrt((vObj.Side1 * vObj.Side1) + (vObj.Side2 * vObj.Side2));
    vA[i][vObj.Hypotenuseidx]=vObj.Hypotenuse.toFixed(2);
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @cooper - I would have to know about the columns name for this script, could I not get them automatically from the header row somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution based on built-in functions will have a better performance than one that use a custom function.

Anyway, the "main problem" with your custom function is that it doesn't return a value. Please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions.

Example from the above link

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```